# Calculate combination index

Tags: php, algorithm, combinations

I'm trying to find a algorithm/base snippet (if that's even possible) to calculate the position of a combination of values - in order not to store all possible combinations.
It could be some simple or complex calculation, I don't know '-'. I just know that I couldn't solve.

For example:

```php
$list = [
    'first' => [
        'a',
        'b',
        'c',
        'd'
    ],
    'second' => [
        'e',
        'f'
    ],
    'third' => [
        'g',
        'h'
    ]
];
$allCombinations = [
    0 => 'first=a,second=e,third=g',
    1 => 'first=a,second=e,third=h',
    2 => 'first=a,second=f,third=g',
    ...
    13 => 'first=d,second=e,third=h',
    14 => 'first=d,second=f,third=g'
];

// For this combination, expected index must be: 13
$combination = [
  'first'  => 'd',
  'second' => 'e',
  'third'  => 'h'
];
```

I'm using this function for calculating all possible combinations (only for testing purposes):

```php
/**
 * @see https://gist.github.com/rxnlabs/88c67bbcfbbb6a1544f7
 */
function calculateCombinations(array $arrays)
{
    //returned array...
    $cartesic = [];

    //calculate expected size of cartesian array...
    $size = (sizeof($arrays) > 0) ? 1 : 0;

    foreach ($arrays as $array) {
        $size = $size * sizeof($array);
    }

    $_arrays = $arrays;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; ++$i) {
        $subvalue = [];

        foreach ($_arrays as $key => $value) {
            $current = current($arrays[$key]);
            $subvalue[$key] = $current;
        }

        $cartesic[$i] = http_build_query($subvalue, '', ',');

        if (0 !== $i) {
            $arrays = array_reverse($arrays);
        }

        //set cursor on next element in the arrays, beginning with the last array
        $arrays = array_reverse($arrays);

        foreach ($arrays as $key => $value) {
            //if next returns true, then break
            if (false !== next($arrays[$key])) {
                break;
            }

            //if next returns false, then reset and go on with previuos array...
            reset($arrays[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $cartesic;
}
```

Any calculation ideas are welcome :)

Note: I saw other similar questions here on StackOverflow but none helped me

Comment: Convert the value into dimension indexes, and calculate the row-major index of those indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Math.

```php
function getIndex($lists, $a, $b, $c) {
    $a_pos = array_search($a, $lists['first']);
    $b_pos = array_search($b, $lists['second']);
    $c_pos = array_search($c, $lists['third']);
    
    $a_len = count($lists['first']);
    $b_len = count($lists['second']);
    $c_len = count($lists['third']);
    
    return $c_pos + ( $b_pos * $c_len ) + ( $a_pos * $b_len * $c_len );
}
```

If you look at your list of indexes and how the values repeat in the columns it should be obvious how this works.

But once you have lists of indeterminate or changing lengths, non-perfect orderings, or gaps in the lists this will break down immediately. At that point you'll likely need a hash table, and at *that* point you should be putting this data in a database instead.

In fact, you probably should already unless this is purely a learning exercise.

Comment: Very clean.  Please consider editing the question to make this page easier to search for.

Comment: Really very simple, thank you. It's just an exercise, but I hope it helps others with the same question.